# Water leaking behind gutters

Tags: roof, waterproofing, gutters

I'm a new homeowner and found that water is getting behind my gutters and was hoping someone may have a solution for me.

Here's the gutter:

[image]
[image]

Edit: Additional pictures below

[image]
[image]
[image]

Video here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uklOh.jpg

From my research I can't find anything obviously wrong with it.  Any idea what I should be looking into to see why it's doing this?

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear from that video; just where on the gutter is the water coming from?

Comment: To clarify: The water is NOT dripping down the face of the gutter to the back?

Comment: I haven't looked at the gutter from a top down view when it's been raining but I did take a couple of other pictures showing where the water is coming from.

[Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/OGjiirr)

It wasn't raining as hard in these pictures.  I will try to get a video from the top down next time it rains or if I can get a hose up there.

Comment: Shingles do not extend far enough beyond the facia board. Also as already commented on yiu have to be certain that the gutter is emptying not overflowing. Check fir blocked downspouts.

Comment: The gutters are clear and have no blockage. What would be my options for extending it further? Could I get a gutter apron or something that tucks under the shingles to extend it out? Or is the only option to have someone replace that row of shingles with something longer?

Comment: @AroundPolandTravel is the drip edge installed as shown, over the back portion of the gutter everywhere, or 1 - is there a gap between both, 2 - the drip edge is behind the gutter somewhere else? That portion shows that the water should be traveling from the drip edge into the gutter.

Comment: @DanielGriscom
I haven't looked at the gutter from a top down view when it's been raining but I did take a couple of other pictures showing where the water is coming from. It wasn't raining as hard in these pictures. I will try to get a video from the top down next time it rains or if I can get a hose up there. [Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/OGjiirr)

Comment: @Kris The gutters are clear and have no blockage. What would be my options for extending it further? Could I get a gutter apron or something that tucks under the shingles to extend it out? Or is the only option to have someone replace that row of shingles with something longer?

Comment: @riseagainst I believe the drip edge runs the whole length of the gutter and looks the exact same down this whole stretch.  I will need to double check that but to my recollection I believe it is all the same.

Comment: Lift the shingles up and examine fir evidence that water is wicking back under shingle and dropping behind drip edge. Clean and seal between shingle and drip edge with a bead of black jack roof sealant  or another high quality sealant.

Comment: @Kris I lifted the shingles up I don't see anywhere where the water could be getting in unless I'm missing something.  See pictures [here](https://imgur.com/a/xr6N8Nh)

Comment: It may be an issue with flashing at the brick and shingle interface. I don’t see any step flashing there. Do you have water dripping behind gutters everywhere or just at this end?

Comment: @Kris I've noticed water dripping on other parts of the house.  I haven't paid close attention to other parts of this particular gutter though other than that one spot.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Answer (score 1):

That is a lot of water pouring out of your soffit.

To find roof leaks, we use a garden hose and start at the eave and work our way up the roof.

Often we discover it’s not the roof membrane, (especially if there’s no roof penetrations like roof jacks, skylights, etc.), but rather the joint between the roof and an upper wall. It’s easy to accumulate a significant amount of water if it hits a wall, runs down the wall and then under the roof membrane. The water will run down the roof sheathing until it finds a gap...then flows out.

Comment: If that indeed is the problem, what would a solution be for preventing that?  Would something need to be added between the roof and brick?

I will see if my hose reaches there and test it out to see what I can find.

Comment: Repair is difficult. You’ll need to add “L shaped” flashing that fits under your siding’s underlayment paper then lays on top of your roofing (but fastens to the roof without causing a leak,) so the water runs down the roof to the gutter. It really depends on where you find the leak. Oh, sometimes it takes 10 - 15 minutes of garden hose watering before it starts to show a leak. Go slow.

Comment: Thank you!  I will give that a try this week to see what I can figure out.