# How can I prevent water from running behind my gutters and under shingles near a wall?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, gutters

I've been troubleshooting some issues have been having with water getting into my basement.  Today I took a hose out to try and find out how water is getting behind my gutters and believe I found some potential culprits.

A) In the first 2 pictures you can see there is some space between the drip edge and gutter.  I think water is sneaking in there.  Are there any DIY options to fix this?  Could something like a gutter apron be slide under the shingles to help get it into gutters?

B) In the last 2 pictures you can see the siding and brick meet up with roof on this part of the house.  I think the water is getting between them, running down, and then pouring out under the gutters.  What options do I have to prevent water from getting in there?  Just getting flashing installed?  Is flashing a DIY project?  It seems like something that may need professional installation.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in most of the photos, it looks like the drip edge is way too close to the fascia. it should actually be a pinky width out, to stop fat water droplets from bridging the gap to the wall and capilariling (not a real word) behind the gutter. water should run down it and fall unimpeded into the gutter. water doesn't typically go up, so don't worry about some blowing behind the edge up into the gap; that's a tiny amount compared to water that will seep up a close cranny.

Comment: @dandavis Would you recommend I bend that drip edge away from the fascia?  Or if I hire out for some of the other issues have them just replace it with something else?

Comment: I disagree with that. Drip edge has always been installed tight to the fascia. That's part of what supports it (to keep the upper leg on plane with the roof). It would also look bad from below if there was a gap. Drip edge should usually shed water from the protrusion, not the bottom flange. Also, the drip edge actually secures the top of the fascia so you don't have to put nails in the face, which causes ugly dimpling.

Comment: @isherwood I agree it looks funny, usually being a bit wavy, but that's the right way, at least according to my sources (https://www.thisoldhouse.com/more/installing-drip-edge)...

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/170171/46271. Closely related

Comment: @dandavis, I think you've misinterpreted. The 3/4" recommendation is for the protruding shelf (hem), not the lower flange. They're simply saying that metal drip-edge with an overhang is important. Maaany years of experience confirm that suspicion.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably need professional assistance with this one.  Whether there is a drip edge or not, the shingles should overhang the edge of the roof by about an inch.  The bigger issue is that there is no brick flashing cut into the side of the brick where it meets the roof in the second two pictures.  Some shingles are going to have to come up to correct these problems.  A proper brick flashing should look something like this photo.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Should there also be flashing along the siding portion too or just the brick?

Answer (score 3):

If you install an apron for the gutter it could just go behind the lower flange of the drip edge. Like WoodAireGrill says, the shingles should extend a bit lower than they do. You could also cut some shingles lengthwise and bond them to the lowest existing course using roofing cement to extend the dripline. You'd slide them under and put dabs of cement between the layers.

Normally you'd see "step flashing" on the brick, which interleaves the shingles. Any water that finds its way under the edge of the shingles is directed down over the top of the shingle below. Without that, the water is able to run under all the shingles. You'll want to investigate whether there's step flashing hidden underneath that was installed behind the brick.

There should also be a kick at the bottom of that run, like so, to direct water away from the wall and into the gutter:

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiQyt6x9vXjAhXOVs0KHaRJDt0Qjhx6BAgBEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstructuretech1.com%2Fkickout-flashing%2F&psig=AOvVaw1nma4Z4lcZopg1qNYbAsNU&ust=1565444773051674)</sub>

Comment: Thanks!  That kickout flashing would help a lot too.  Should there also be flashing along the siding portion too or just the brick?

Comment: Depends partly on whether there's proper step flashing in place. Typically you only have a kick at the eave, but there are cases where a second one is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone see a starter strip? I don't. Thats a first line of defense and promotion for proper water shedding.